# How to displays system statistics using query?

Tags: php, oracle, database-performance

Well, I have to say that I don't have much experience with Oracle. My problem is:

I have a server that is running an Oracle database. Sometime, it loads slow and hangs. I need to track to know why. But I don't have permission on this server. I can only run a query via PDO.

Here how I run a query:

```
$db = new PDOOCI\PDO("192.168.x.x:xxxx/something.something;charset=AL32UTF8", "username", "password"); 
$status = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$status->execute();
$r = $status->fetchAll();
var_dump($r);
```

So, I hope that I can use a query to collect some information about server such as CPU load speed, memory, session, etc and draw a chart about it in real-time. By this way I maybe know which time in day it used to slow.

I tried some query below but it return nothing.

```
$status = $db->prepare("SELECT sql_text FROM v$session");
$status = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM v$process");
$status = $db->prepare("select * from V$OSSTAT");
```

I'm not sure whether I'm on wrong way or not :(

Comment: Get your DBA to run an AWR snapshot report. "loads slow and hangs" does not mean much.  You are saying that "select * from table" is slow?  Well, how big is the table?

Comment: No select * from table is just an example to show how I connect and get data. It is a big database in an hospital. Sometime I cannot connect to this database and Iam finding the causes.

Comment: "cannot connect to this database" What does that mean?  Please try to be more specific.  Whole books are written on oracle db performance tuning.  Yes, those views may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather difficult issue. It could be other things than your database that could cause the system to slow. It depends what you have on the server.

Here is a hint on how you could gather information about the queries that where launched this very day: run it every night to know what happened on your database: ***use `V$SQL` Oracle system view***

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$sql 
 WHERE to_date(last_load_time,'YYYY-MM-DD/HH24:MI:SS') > trunc(sysdate)
```

e.g. If you want only the 10 most costly queries, order, then take the 10 top rows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT sql_text, cpu_time, elapsed_time,  last_load_time 
      FROM v$sql 
     WHERE to_date(last_load_time,'YYYY-MM-DD/HH24:MI:SS') > trunc(sysdate)
  ORDER BY cpu_time desc
)WHERE ROWNUM <10
```

> Beware: since you see nothing in `v$session` or other system views, you may need to ask your DBA for extra grants on the database. e.g. you may need something like role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or similar